# How to dinamicaly parse html template using thymeleaf + Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a project and I need users to be able to add content without recompiling the application or using a database. What I want to achieve is for spring to look in a directory called `modules /` for all folders containing a thymeleaf html file and render them according to their name from a single controller. it's possible?.

I have looked for information on how to render a fragment of thymeleaf from java in real time but I have not found any information.

Comment: Can you provide an example, ideally with some relevant data and code, if possible? I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

with the help of this, we can navigate our template path as per our desired location.

```
@Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver().setPrefix("file://C:/test/");// this is
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("XHTML");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        return templateResolver;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a solution.
use this in application properties file

```
project.base-dir=file:///E:/Work/WorkSpace/RND WorkSpace/sk
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=${project.base-dir}/src/main/resources/templates/
```